# sql command timeout potential issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, ado.net

How is it I can upload a 20+ mb file to a webserver, but have it timeout when I try to download it? I would think the upload would timeout as well.

Both are using ado.net sqlclient. The event log shows SqlException timeout occurred when attempting to download.

This [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/spike/archive/2008/07/31/timeout-expired-the-timeout-period-elapsed-prior-to-completion-of-the-operation-or-the-server-is-not-responding.aspx) looks like a possible lead. But again, why wouldn't it timeout on the upload?

```
    public DataTable ExecuteDataTable(string sql)
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection();
        DataTable dt;
        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            SqlCommand dateformatcmd = new SqlCommand("set dateformat " + myDateFormat, conn);
            dateformatcmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, conn);
            //Walk through the parameters
            foreach (string name in param.Keys)
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(name, param[name]));
            }
            da.SelectCommand = cmd;
            dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
        }
        catch (SqlException)
        { 
            throw;
        }
        finally
        {
            if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
        return dt;
    }
```

Comment: Can you post the code?

Comment: Have you confirmed your upload and download transmission rates? Although unlikely, you could have a faster upload rate.

Comment: What have you set as the timeout for the SqlCommand? By default it is 30 seconds. You might have to increase it if your download is taking more time than that. Try setting cmd.Timeout = 180 or some huge value to account for the large file download.